# Multiple Access tables import to mysql db

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I receive an access file with multiple tables that I need to import to a MySQL db. I need to either convert all the tables to txt files for loading or need a perl script or something to convert and then I can write out load statements. Doing this manually takes forever and I need to do this for about 20 Access files with 16 tables each. The company where I am at does not want to use anything other than Navicat,Perl Scripts, VB Scripts or straight MySQL code to process this. Any ideas? Something in Access 2007 that can do this for multiple tables instead of the export tool doing one by one?

Any idea or suggestion will help.

Comment: Please consider migrating to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

You can download [this](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2s/info.php) utility to help you to convert an access file into a sql file. Now, you can import a sql file into mySQL.